# Code Breaking ( Sort of )

Tags: riddle, mathematics

So someone sent me this code breaking/riddle to solve and I got really confused on it. I do need help on it,

The Code needs to come out into a Phrase ( group of words )

CLUE 1: 2210232013400 - 2311032013400

Hint no.1 : Depending how you look at it, there are either 5 or 10 steps to this, and I doubt anyone will get very far without the second hint, sorry not sorry.
Hint no.2 : The numbers are a range
Hint no.3 : The 5 and 10 are intentional in existence and placement

These are the clues/hints. I need to make CLUE #1 into a phrase but not sure how I can do that with the numbers.

Anyone that can solve this / help me ?

Comment: Can you tell us some more about where this comes from? Any context might be helpful in trying to figure it out.

Comment: This is all the context I have. CLUE #1 is the Given, while the "prove" part is the Phrase. It did come from a website named Wynncraft.com on the forums area. It is an event to get a prize, ( in game item ).  The Community event is labeled "100k giveaway " or something like that. Maybe you can find something there about the 5 and 10 ? Again, this is all they really gave us.

Comment: It might also be an algebra code breaking type, which it seems it is pointing to it most.

Comment: Ah, if this comes from an ongoing contest then I'm afraid we can't have it here until after the contest is over. It seems like that's one week from when it was posted, which I think was Sunday, so I'm going to lock this for a week. After that it's fair game.

Comment: (The lock message talks about "disputes about its content"; of course there's no actual dispute. There's a fixed set of messages available and this was the closest.)